# hdf to gtiff, reprojecting, cropping with a shapefile in batch using R

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, r, geotiff-tiff, hdf

I have some raster data from MODIS, with hdf format.
I want to convert them into GeoTIFF, reproject them and crop them based on my shapefile. 
I was able to do it in GDAL, in batch mode, with the following code, but I don't know how to do it in R.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff input.hdf output.tif
gdalwarp -t_srs "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84" input.tif output.tif
gdalwarp -cutline tl_2013_18_cousub.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha input.tif OUTPUT.tif
```

I use the following code in R, but it's just for the converting to GeoTIFF and also it does not provide the result with TIFF format. (I don't know why)

```
    library(gdalUtils)

files <- dir(pattern = ".hdf")
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  sds <- get_subdatasets(files[i]) # the input files have different subdatatsets, and I need only the first one
  gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = paste0("new_",basename(files[i])), of = "GTiff")
}
```

based on your comment, I wrote the following code though it has errors,
can anyone help me with the issues in comments?

```
   library(gdalUtils)
        files <- list.files(path=".../test", pattern="*.hdf", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
    for (i in 1:length(files)){
    sds <- get_subdatasets(files[i])
    gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = paste0(basename(files[i]),".tif"), of = "GTiff")
    } 
#first issue: the file name would be like "filename.hdf.tif" how can I remove "hdf" part to make it like "filename.tif"

    shp <- shapefile("tl_2013_18_cousub.shp")

#second issue: I had to write another loop, can it be merged with previous loop to save time in running process?
    files <- list.files(path=".....", pattern="*.tif", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
    for (i in 1:length(files)){
    sds <- raster(files[i])
    xp <- projectRaster(sds, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84") 
    writeRaster(xp, file = paste0("prj_",basename(files[i])))
# third issue: the saved file has different resolution! how can I maintain the original resolution 

    cr <- crop(xp, shp)  
    writeRaster(cr, file = paste0("crp_",basename(files[i])))
# Forth issue: it guves me error: "Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap"
    }
```

Comment: any idea on how to remove issues in comments?

Answer (score 2):

That command line code in R roughly is

```
library(raster)
x <- raster("input.hdf")  ## 1
xp <- projectRaster(x, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=16 +datum=WGS84") # 2
shp <- shapefile("tl_2013_18_cousub.shp")
crop(xp, shp)  # 3
```

But (and there are endless more caveats to these caveats):

1. requires rgdal and your system's rgdal might not have HDF4 support, and it might have multiple subdatasets so require sds string rather than file
2. Better to have a target raster with defined extents, crs, and resolution, otherwise raster (and GDAL also) will auto-guess extents/resolution for you
3. Really we should `spTransform(sp, projection(xp))` rather than the lossy raster reprojection

I'd be trying

```
library(raster)
x <- raster("input.hdf")  ## 1
shp <- shapefile("tl_2013_18_cousub.shp")
crop(xp, spTransform(shp, projection(xp))
```

Comment: can you see the edit? can you help me with those issues in comments?